# Perlin noise algorithm

Tags: perlin-noise

I'm having difficulty understanding a lot of the highly mathematical papers available online describing how Perlin noise generation works, and I'm wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a more accessible introduction. I am looking to use Perlin noise in an application to create 2D textures.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that the original Perlin noise algorithm has been deprecated by the author. Ken Perlin designed a new version: [Simplex Noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963388/fastest-perlin-like-3d-noise-algorithm)

There is a good explanation of Simplex Noise with Java implementation [here](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf).

Comment: please note that simplex noise is patented! So even if its better, you might not want to use it!

Comment: It is only patented for texture generation in 3D and beyond which makes it suitable for terrain generation among other things.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the book [Texturing and Modeling, A Procedural Approach](http://books.google.cl/books?id=GWQ_hz2sIMcC&dq=Texturing+and+Modeling,+A+Procedural+Approach&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=es&ei=JGpHTKTdNcTflgfqq8yaBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false), starting in page 67 there's a nice description and source code for gradient noises, perlin noise is just another gradient noise.

There's also a implementation in [GPU Gems 2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter26.html).

Perlin noise itself doesn't use much advanced math, you only need to know about linear interpolation, lattices and random values.